# On a particular kind of simplicial complex with maximum facet size of $3$.

Tags: algebraic-topology, commutative-algebra, simplicial-complex, algebraic-combinatorics, cohen-macaulay

Let $\Delta$ be an abstract [simplicial complex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_simplicial_complex)  on $n$ vertices such that $\max \{|F| : F$ is a face of $\Delta \}=3$.

Let $f_2$ be the number of faces of size (cardinality) $3$ and $f_1$ be the number of faces of size (cardinality) $2$.

Also assume that the [Stanley-Reisner ring](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stanley%E2%80%93Reisner_ring)  $k[\Delta]$ is Cohen-Macaulay for every field $k$ of characteristic $0$.

My question is: If $3f_2=2f_1$, then is it necessarily true that $3n-6\ge f_1$ ?

NOTE: Some examples of simplicial complexes with $3f_2=2f_1$ are [pseudo-manifolds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudomanifold).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. In fact, for pseudomanifolds (without boundary) the opposite inequality holds.  If $\Delta$ is a pseudomanifold of dimension $n$, then $$H_n(\Delta,\mathbb{Z}) \cong \begin{cases} \mathbb{Z} & \text{if $\Delta$ is orientable} \\ 0 & \text{if $\Delta$ is not orientable.} \end{cases}$$  If particular, if $n=2$, then $\chi(\Delta) \le 2$. Then

$3\chi(\Delta)=3f_0-3f_1+3f_2=3f_0-3f_1+2f_1=3f_0-f_1 \le 6$. Thus $3f_0-6 \le f_1$.

If we further assume $\Delta$ is Cohen-Macaulay (over some field), then $\chi(\Delta)=2$ if $\Delta$ is orientable, and $\chi(\Delta)=1$ if $\Delta$ is not orientable. The same argument as above then shows that $f_1=3f_0-6$ in the orientable case, and $f_1=3f_0-3$ in the non-orientable case.

For a concrete example of the orientable case, take a triangulation of a $2$-dimensional sphere, and for the non-orientable case, take a triangulation of the real projective plane $\mathbb{R}P^2$. The latter of these is not Cohen-Macaulay over every field, but is Cohen-Macaulay over fields of characteristic $0$ (or any field of characteristic not $2$).

Comment: Thanks for the answer ... could you please suggest some reference for this (especially the calculation for the homology and the Euler characteristic for pseudomanifolds ) ?

Comment: @user The Euler characteristic calculations follow immediately from the homology calculation since $\chi(\Delta)=\operatorname{rank} H_0(\Delta,\mathbb{Z})-\operatorname{rank} H_1(\Delta,\mathbb{Z})+\operatorname{rank} H_2(\Delta,\mathbb{Z})$.  References to the fact about homology can be found in Richard Stanley's "Combinatorics and Commutative Algebra" or "Basic Concepts of Algebraic Topology" by Fred Croon. Neither of these contain worked out proofs of this fact (parts are exercises in the latter) but the point is to consider what the conditions say about the last map in the chain complex.